# I can't download M3U8 HLS playlist from a streaming server without facing CORS errors?

Tags: javascript, cors, avplayer, http-live-streaming

In order to monitor some HLS video streaming that we are operating, I made a HTML web page which include:

- videojs players (in `<video>` element)
- some javascript that runs every 10 seconds to grab and analyse m3u8 playlists content (such as detecting frozen playlist)

This works with most of the streaming sites I am monitoring but one.

When I used the playlist URL as `src` in the video player, all is fine and video is played. However when my script is using a XMLHttpRequest() to get the M3U8 I am blocked by Chrome for CORS reasons:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.xxxx.com/cdn/live/video/xxxxx.m3u8?sec=xxxxxx' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I originally went the lazy way using Chrome extension "Allow CORS" v0.1.1 from Muyor but it seems it is not working anymore. Current Chrome is 76.0.3809.132 and this was still working a few days ago.

Now I would prefer to make it correctly but despite reading as much as possible about CORS I still can't understand why videojs can read the playlist (videojs is JavaScript isn't it ?) and my script can't. Both running on the same browser, in the same page, accessing the same URL.

Here is a example of my Javascript code to grab a playlist:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
    // there lies the code that analyse the downloaded playlist and write to the HTML document in case of errors
}
xhr.open( "GET", checkitem.url, true );
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*'); // doesn't help
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // doesn't help neither
xhr.send();
```

This works fine with all of sites but one.
I can't ask the server to change anything.
The behavior is the same whether I open the html file in the browser from the filesystem or through a local webserver.

As videojs can access the URL I believe there must be something I can do from my side.

Thanks

Comment: your server should allow the domain where the html is hosted

Answer (score 0):

CORS is doing exactly what it is designed to do. Having a way around it would make CORS useless.

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` are not client side headers, they are server side headers.

There are a few options:

- The server administrator must update the server config to include the necessary headers
- Or you can configure a proxy server to proxy the requests
- Or you can modify and compile the chrome source code.

Comment: Hi @szatmary, so could you please explain me why VideoJS which is a JavaScript video player can access the URL ?
If they can, there must be something that I don't do correctly.

Comment: I don't know your entire setup, but I'm guessing the video JS player is hosted from the same domain as the playlist, whereas your code is not.

Comment: No it isn't.
My web page is local on my PC and is getting the videojs code from :
```<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.4.6/video.min.js"></script></script>```

Which is a totally different domain than the server hosting the video stream (ie the m3u8 file).
All run in the same web page : the videojs player and my own javascript.

Unfortunately I can't share the URL and it may also geoblocked only to my country so not easy to provide a complete example to reproduce.

Comment: Then something non standard is happening, possibly custom server logic.